# android one signal notification return on app's previous state or page

Tags: java, android, onesignal

Good day everyone, I am here to ask about onesignal notification on android. I want to return to the app's previous state/page when the notification is clicked. thank you for your help on advance.

Comment: Please share what you've got so far. See also: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize which activity you want to show when a OneSignal notification is opened if the launcher Activity defined in your AndroidManifest.xml isn't what you want. See [Open a different Activity](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-notification-customizations#open-a-different-activity) at the bottom of the Android Customizing Notifications documenation.

The OneSignal SDK currently does not have an option to resume the app at the current Activity however you can use the above to create an Activity that will just close when opened to make Android go backward to your last active Activity.

Thanks.